# AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: auth.decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-decorators

Getting an error when I try to use a custom decorator on a view. From what I've been able to find the issue seems to be with not using @wraps on the decorated function but I do that and still seem to get an error that the view function mapping exists already.

```
def logout_required(url="/"):
    """
    Redirect a user to a specified location if they are already signed in.

    :param url: URL to be redirected to if invalid
    :type url: str
    :return: Function
    """

    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
            if current_user.is_authenticated:
                return redirect(url)

            return f(*args, **kwargs)

        return decorated_function

    return decorator
```

views.py

```
@blueprint.route("/login")
@logout_required
def login():
    return "LOGIN"


@blueprint.route("/logout")
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    flash("You have been logged out.", "success")
    return redirect(url_for("auth.login"))


@blueprint.route("/register")
@logout_required
def register():
    return "REGISTER"
```

If it helps, the stack trace as well:

```
website_1   | [2020-06-29 05:15:03 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
website_1   | [2020-06-29 05:15:03 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
website_1   | [2020-06-29 05:15:03 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
website_1   | [2020-06-29 05:15:03 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
website_1   | [2020-06-29 05:15:03 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
website_1   | Traceback (most recent call last):
website_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
website_1   |     worker.init_process()
website_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
website_1   |     self.load_wsgi()
website_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
website_1   |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
website_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
website_1   |     self.callable = self.load()
website_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
website_1   |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
website_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
website_1   |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
website_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 411, in import_app
website_1   |     app = app(*args, **kwargs)
website_1   |   File "/project/app/app.py", line 27, in create_app
website_1   |     register_blueprints(app)
website_1   |   File "/project/app/app.py", line 50, in register_blueprints
website_1   |     app.register_blueprint(auth.blueprint)
website_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 98, in wrapper_func
website_1   |     return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
website_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1168, in register_blueprint
website_1   |     blueprint.register(self, options, first_registration)
website_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/blueprints.py", line 256, in register
website_1   |     deferred(state)
website_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/blueprints.py", line 294, in <lambda>
website_1   |     self.record(lambda s: s.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, view_func, **options))
website_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/blueprints.py", line 86, in add_url_rule
website_1   |     **options
website_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 98, in wrapper_func
website_1   |     return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
website_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1284, in add_url_rule
website_1   |     "existing endpoint function: %s" % endpoint
website_1   | AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: auth.decorator
```

Comment: You have to call `logout_required` before decorating a function - `@logout_required("/")`. Your "decorator" `logout_required` is actually a function that takes an argument `url` and returns a decorator

Comment: That fixes it. Didn't realize I needed to use decorators with arguments with parentheses whether or not I have arguments. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't realize I needed to call decorators even if they have a default argument defined. Can only use decorators the way I did on the question if they have no argument at all.